# Logout (write a row to the DB) after 20mins of inactivity in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'd like to find a tutorial that shows how to logout after a certain period of inactivity.

By logging out, i mean writing a Row to my SQL database. The database table was designed with a column called user_status. When a user logs in, ASP writes a row called "logged in" into the database table. I want to find an automatic mechanism that writes a Row to the database after a certain pd of inactivity

Comment: I believe that IIS has features to manage your session and provide timeout settings for your session.

Comment: To what end?  Why do you want to know about the lack of activity?  For example, if it were for some kind of database cleanup deal, I'd be more inclined to run a job in SQL Server that would look for users that are logged in but have not generated any activity in x minutes.  As @maple_shaft mentions, ASP.NET already has baked in session management mechanisms for the "front end" side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't provide any event that can run after inactivity. You might be able to tie into the session ending event (Session_end if I remember correctly) but I know that event isn't very reliable.

The easiest way I can think of to do this will be to track the users last activity time in a table. Then update the last activity time on every action (both display and post backs). Have another routine that runs every minute scanning the table for people who have been inactive for 20 minutes. When those people are found, reset their user_status entry.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific as to have a routine that runs every minute checking for people who haven't done anything for the last 20 minutes? thanks

Comment: I'd develop a console app and control it through a job scheduler. If you don't have a job scheduler, you can use the built-in Windows Task Scheduler but that will only let you run every five minutes.

Comment: @user133466, You don't need to write a routine because IIS already can control this for you.  http://www.checkbox.com/kb/articles/kb-1036-survey_software_iis_timeout_settings.asp  All you have to do is configure this and then do what others are suggesting and put custom code in the session end event.

Comment: The specifics of where the routine should live and who should be responsible for handling it depend on what the routine actually needs to do AND WHY... as I asked above.  ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do something like that in the SessionEnd event of the Application (Global.asax).

However, the SessionEnd is only raised if the sessionstate mode is InProc.